# MySQL Connector/C++ 8 X Plugin disabled

Tags: c++, mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-x-devapi

I am working on a server application in c++ that will connect to a `MySQL Server` using `MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0`.

The server has `X plugin` disabled and I cannot change that.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/x-plugin-disabling.html

It is possible to connect to this server using `MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0` ?

I found nothing in the docs. 
I have tried to modify the protocol in the session connection string from `mysqlx://` to `tcp://` but my config supports only `mysqlx`.

There is something I am missing the connection is possible only using `MySQL Connector/C++ 1.x` ?

The error I am receiving is `CDK Error: unexpected message`. I can successfully connect to a local MySql database instance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question tags, I guess you are using Amazon RDS and, as far as I can tell, at the moment, Amazon RDS does not support the X Plugin and consequently does not support X Protocol connections (`mysqlx://` on port 33060 by default).

However, Connector/C++ also supports [JDBC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-introduction.html) and whatnot, so you should be able to connect to any MySQL instance on port 3306 as well.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js